# How do I make a list with columns (like a file browser) in html (or javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a list container with multiple columns (like you see in a file browser, with the "name", "size", "data modified" columns) in html and javascript. Is this possible?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: sure its possible. so is apple juice and airplanes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a grid.  [Here's my favorite.](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki)  SlickGrid has resizable columns, is highly flexible—and most importantly—allows an effectively unlimited number of rows without slowing down the browser.

[Live demo.](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html)

Comment: Doesn't it use CSS? dasen666 asked for HTML and JavaScript only.

Comment: @Radek: Are you honestly suggesting that someone is doing modern web development *without* CSS?

Comment: "in html and javascript". I do not see the word 'CSS' in there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a little known html element called a table.

Comment: @Radek Pro-Grammer ha i dont. im referring to the universal `he` like the universal `they` and `them` :-P